# How to send request on one port and response that request on another port in C# windows application

Tags: c#

I am using TCPCLient and TcpListenersockets. Here am sending request on port 19000 to 192.168.7.56 IP machine. After giving response from that machine i need to response that i got msg to that machine on port 20000.

Means i want to use one port for all requests and another port for response purpose. Is this possible in C#? Is my scenario correct?

Why this requirement is... In TcpListener socket I am getting continues requests from other machine. So it must be always available to get those requests....

After getting request on TcpListener I need to response them that I got req like aknowledgement on different port.

Please suggest how to implement this scenario?

Thanks,
Syed Chand Basha

Answer (score 0):

well the common pattern is

one port and behind a pool for processing request (here you can verify the load the server or maximum clients for processing..etc)

when request enter the pool will create an new thread for process that request
while the main pool can still listening request

also exist other thread monitor the threads for timeout or errors so it can kill process for errors or timeout o long processing

regards